# Intent filter worked on Oreo but not on Nougat

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have an intent filter to handle excel.xlsx files and it works nicely in android 8 but when I try it in android 7 it doesn't work 
my intent filter is this :

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                android:scheme="file" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `android:scheme` attribute? That could be the problem if there was a change made related to how the document is stored.

Comment: yes that didn't work

Comment: it mades some error  "missing uri"